# ReleaseObject of ITinyIoCObjectLifetimeProvider is not being called

Tags: c#, ioc-container, hangfire, tinyioc

I have implemented custom lifetime provider in order to have singleton DB context per **job in hangfire**. The problem in code below is that created instances are not being released.

My question is: Why `ReleaseObject` method is not called?

```
public class JobContextLifetimeProvider : TinyIoCContainer.ITinyIoCObjectLifetimeProvider
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> Locator = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

        public object GetObject()
        {
            var key = JobContext.JobId;
            return Locator.ContainsKey(key) ? Locator[key] : null;
        }

        public void SetObject(object value)
        {
            var key = JobContext.JobId;
            Locator[key] = value;

            if (value is IDataContext)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Created data context {0}", value.GetHashCode());
            }
        }

        public void ReleaseObject()
        {
            var item = GetObject() as IDisposable;

            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Dispose();
                SetObject(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ReleaseObject` not being called?  Or is the object returned by `GetObject()` not an `IDisposable`, and therefore, `SetObject(null)` never gets called when `ReleaseObject` is called?

Comment: ReleaseObject is not called, returned object is disposable (DbContext)